# How to do a time out for get data from the db?

Tags: java, android

I have a question.
I need to do timeout for get data from firebase real time database.

I have a splash activity inside which I get data from the db.
I want to do this so that the next activity opens only when the data has arrived.

Right now, I'm opening the next activity after X seconds and not really checking if the data has arrived.

Right now, I'm opening the next activity after X seconds and not really checking if the data has arrived.

Splash Activity that contain views.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SplashModel {

    private SplashPresenter presenter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        presenter = new SplashPresenter(this);
        presenter.loadUserDetailsData();
    }

    @Override
    public void showLoader() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.splash_container, new SplashFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void openMainActivity() {
        new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                },
                2000);
    }
}
```

Splash presenter that loading data from server.

```
public class SplashPresenter {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference users = db.getReference("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("UserDetails");
    private SplashModel model;

    public SplashPresenter(SplashModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void loadUserDetailsData() {
        model.showLoader();
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                UserSingleton retrievedData = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserSingleton.class);
                UserSingleton.getInstance().setmUserName(retrievedData.getmUserName());
                UserSingleton.getInstance().setmEmail(retrievedData.getmEmail());
                UserSingleton.getInstance().setmEventDate(retrievedData.getmEventDate());
                UserSingleton.getInstance().setmEventLocation(retrievedData.getmEventLocation());
                UserSingleton.getInstance().setmPartnerName(retrievedData.getmPartnerName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };
        users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
       model.openMainActivity();
    }
}

public interface SplashModel {
    void showLoader();
    void openMainActivity();

}
```

I need that the next activity will opens only after data received.

How can i do it?

Comment: You can create, for example, an event listener and fire this event when your required data has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Open MainActivity from onDataChange so once data loaded then only openMainActivity() will called.

```
public void loadUserDetailsData() {
        model.showLoader();
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                UserSingleton retrievedData = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserSingleton.class);
                UserSingleton.getInstance().setmUserName(retrievedData.getmUserName());
                UserSingleton.getInstance().setmEmail(retrievedData.getmEmail());
                UserSingleton.getInstance().setmEventDate(retrievedData.getmEventDate());
                UserSingleton.getInstance().setmEventLocation(retrievedData.getmEventLocation());
                UserSingleton.getInstance().setmPartnerName(retrievedData.getmPartnerName());
                model.openMainActivity();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };
        users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

    }
```

and open MainActivity in openMainActivity() without delay like this

```
  @Override
  public void openMainActivity() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     finish();
}
```